# How to differentiate document requests from variable requests? and how to allow for urls that are not expected?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My last post was met by smarmy, unhelpful "answers" (comments), so i'll get right to it:

if I have an htaccess file like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&subject=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

how can I allow for other url variable names and values to be handled... say for instance I want to add extra unexpected url vars to this scenario

```
/page/subject?urlvar1=value1&urlvar2=value2
```

and get the page I want without creating unexpected results?

Any real help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate questions will collect close votes, and possibly downvotes.  This one is much more concise than your original question, so I would suggest you delete the first one.

Comment: cool, thanks for the tip... deleted.

Comment: Can you clarify... if the url variable is unexpected, then how can there be a correct page to send it to? Can you provide an example of an unexpected request and what you where you would like it to be redirected to?

Comment: i'm saying that if i want to throw in a variable that works in my php code, but don't really want to have to take the time to spell out in the .htaccess file, like something that i'm using for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add [QSA] (query string append) flag to your rules.

As a general advice, it's better to have only one generic rule like

```
 RewriteRule .* index.php?path=$0
```

and parse the path at php level. This is much more flexible and transparent.

to elaborate, here's the complete setup

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?path=$0 [QSA]
```

index.php

```
<pre>
<?php 
print_r($_GET);
?>
</pre>
```

when called like `www.example.com/foo/bar/baz?quux=123&blah=456` this prints

```
Array
(
    [path] => foo/bar/baz
    [quux] => 123
    [blah] => 456
)
```

the only thing that's left is to parse $_GET['path'] with explode or regular expressions.

Comment: ok, now that's what i'm talking about!  thank you... so i tried that and i get internal config error with the following:

RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f   
RewriteRule .* index.php?path=$0 [QSA]   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA]   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f   
RewriteRule ^ - [QSA]   
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1&subject=$2 [QSA]   
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA, L]   

do you see anything wrong with this?  thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 - I wasn't aware of the `[QSA]` flag.  I just tried it, it works like a charm.

Comment: +1 for parsing with php instead of messing with htaccess. That's how I do it and it's way easier to get it working if you ever need to make it work on lighttpd or some other web server.

Comment: @Lucas - try it with your existing rule set first before you change everything.  The rules you had worked with `[QSA]` in the test I did.  Stereofrog's suggestion to only have a single rule works only if you write some PHP code to handle the path string for every request.  You might not want to jump into that just yet.

Comment: @stereofrog... so you're saying if i am processing a request like: /page/subject ... then that equals /index.php?path=/page/subject ? and then i parse the variables?  that sounds like a dream!  yes?

Comment: qsa works!!! now, if people could quit being so snide :\ thanks, everyone, for all your help!!! :)